# Преобразовать дату php в нужный формат?

Tags: php

В переменной $date хранится дата вида к примеру `2014-06-25`.
Как перевести эту дату в вид `25.06.2014`?

Comment: Вы шутите? Это же элементарные функции, которые должен знать даже новичек. Пусть даже не класс [DateTime][1], но [date()][2], [strtotime()][3] и т.д....

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php
   [2]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php
   [3]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Comment: О мои глаза. Вопрос как запустить Php файл вы уже задавали? Я пропустил ((

Comment: Такие элементарные вещи надо знать, как минимум уметь гуглить, а лучше сразу в документации смотреть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать дату в нормальный вид?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369696/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Answer (score 14):

```
$date = "2014-06-25";
echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($date));
```